# A string does not contain a number

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Looking for addresses in a table that **does not** contain a number

So "Smith Street" or "James Road" etc

I tried using:

`address_street not like '%[0-9]%'`

but this did not work, as the results returned everything that is not literally that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of investigation with strings you can use regular expressions and the corresponding functions offered by BigQuery. For instance with `REGEX_CONTAINS`:

```
with sample as (
    select "39, Albert street" AS address_street
    union all select "Private Drive"
    union all select "10, Downing Street"
    union all select "Buckingham palace"
)

select * from sample 
where not regexp_contains(address_street, r'\d')
```

returns

[image]

Comment: awesome! this works, I also found out that  '[[:digit:]]' works as well in the meantime. thank you!!

Comment: I didn't know that one ! ^^ Thank you as well !